# Sitelinks and domain name

Tags: google, sitelinks

We have a company website, let says it's `http://www.mycompany.com`. URL without the `www` (`http://mycompany.com`) is working and displays the same website.

When Googling `mycompany`, first result is the website, with no site links.

When Googling `mycompany.com`, first result is the website, with site links.

When Googling `www.mycompany.com`, first result is the website, with different site links.

Why is there no site links for "mycompany" keyword?

Comment: What do you mean Google Links? Are you saying about Sitelinks?

Comment: Yes, I mean site links (not very familiar with SEO stuffs). Post edited.

Comment: Possible, but... mycompany.com != www.mycompany.com is fine. But why no site links at all with just mycompany?

Comment: How many results does `mycompany` return compared with `mycompany.com`?

Comment: `mycompany`: 1 060 000, `mycompany.com` : 12 200 000 (yes, more).

Answer (score 0):

Google [says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) that

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

All these process are automated and so we can't say why Google not showing sitelinks for your 'mycompany' keyword. We have only access to demote a sitelink but we can't manually add a link.